# To lower case using if else/ for

Tags: javascript

I am the very begginer (only if/else, for, while, slice etc) and i ve got a problem: so i wrote Hangman game. I need to put in there code saying ‘’let’s  player upper case guess letter transform to lowercase one every time he puts uppercase letter”

1. Did i choose the right place for this new code in existing code?
2. Were my thoughts about appropriate code more or less right?
3. If not: what s wrong then?

```js
var words = ["fish", "monkey", "pioni", "agreable"];
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
  answerArray[i] = "_";
}
var ramainingLetters = randomWord.length;

//Game circle
while (ramainingLetters > 0) {
  alert(answerArray.join(" "));

  var guess = prompt("Guess a letter or press cancel to exit game");
  if (guess === null) {
    break;
  } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Enter only one letter");
  } else if (guess == guess.toUpperCase()) {
    guess = guess.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    //renew game cycle
    for (var j = 0; j < randomWord.length; j++) {
      if (randomWord[j] === guess) {
        answerArray[j] = guess;
        ramainingLetters--;
      }
    }
  }

  // stop game 
}
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert(" Cool! this word was " + randomWord);
```

Comment: code review SE might be a better place for this sort of question

Comment: What s SE? Where d i find it?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would say that testing the letter for uppercase is not needed, as lowering a lowercase does nothing. But more importantly, read the difference between `toLowerCase` and `toLocaleLowerCase`, it might come in handy if you were working with languages such as Spain, French or other European languages.

Comment: SE = stack exchange

Comment: Notice: if the guess is uppercased, the condition after `else if` fulfilled, and the lowercasing is executed.
BUT!! the code of `//renew game cycle` is NOT executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve your problem by converting the chosen word to uppercase and everytime the user puts in a letter, make that uppercase too.

```
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)].toUpperCase();
```

And convert your quess always to uppercase

```
guess = guess.toUpperCase();
```

This way everything is consistent.
If they type in a letter in lowercase its getting converted to uppercase and compared with the word also in uppercase.